# NSIS Get file version of EXE that is UPX Compressed

Tags: nsis, upx

I have been using a little NSIS script for a few years that grabs the version of the EXE so I can display it in the installers welcome text.

I got the script here: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Invoking_NSIS_run-time_commands_on_compile-time

```
!define File "C:\MyFile.exe"

OutFile "GetVersion.exe"
SilentInstall silent

Section

 ## Get file version
 GetDllVersion "${File}" $R0 $R1
  IntOp $R2 $R0 / 0x00010000
  IntOp $R3 $R0 & 0x0000FFFF
  IntOp $R4 $R1 / 0x00010000
  IntOp $R5 $R1 & 0x0000FFFF
  StrCpy $R1 "$R2.$R3.$R4.$R5"

 ## Write it to a !define for use in main script
 FileOpen $R0 "$EXEDIR\Version.txt" w
  FileWrite $R0 '!define Version "$R1"'
 FileClose $R0

SectionEnd
```

Recently I started using UPX to compress the EXE of the application.

Now that it is UPX compressed, the file version script no longer works, I'm guessing due to non standard header layout.

How can I read the file version from a UPX compressed EXE?

UPDATE:  This is closed now but I discovered later this is likely to do with some kind of elevated permissions issue and running the command over a mapped drive.

Comment: How did you invoke UPX? Is the version information still visible in Explorer and other applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when using `UPX --ultra-brute test.exe` the version information block did not get compressed when I tried. Are you using special UPX switches? Have you tried `--keep-resource=%resourceid%`?

If you are using NSIS v3 you can use `!getdllversion` to get the version at compile-time without having to use `!system`.

Comment: I use no switches just "upx myfile.exe"  I will try that flag though

Comment: Actually it looks like Finalbuilder did have switches in it. I unchecked "Compress Resources" and it is now working.  Thank you!